# CODEIGNITER how to insert user_ID to mySQL when that user_ID is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

this is the error page

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`latihan_ci`.`adventure`, CONSTRAINT `adventure_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

INSERT INTO `adventure` (`name`, `category`, `place`, `state`) VALUES ('semeru', 'gunung', 'asa', 'asd')

and this is my controller

```
public function addTrip(){
    $this->load->model('userModel');
    $newTrip = ['name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                'place' => $this->input->post('place'),
                'state' => $this->input->post('state'),

                ];
            $data['users'] = $this->userModel->getUserId()->result(); 

    $this->db->insert('adventure',$newTrip);
    $this->db->insert('adventure',$data);

    redirect('userController/profile');
}
```

and this is my Model

```
public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->db->get('users',['user_id']);
    }
```

so how to add the user_ID to the mySQL when the value is user_ID that is already login..Thanks alot

Comment: what is the output of `$data['users']`? can you show us by printing it out?

Comment: post output of `$data['users']`

Answer (score 1):

when you are login at that time `user_id` store in session after use

**controller**

```
$newTrip = ['name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
            'place' => $this->input->post('place'),
            'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'user_id'=>$this->session->userdata('userdata'),
];
```