# how to insert Foreign Key ID when I login to other table CODEIGNETER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

I want insert my user_ID to table adventure base on which user is login. but the problem is I never get the value from the user login the value is always NULL

this is the error page :

> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'user_id' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `adventure` (`name`, `category`, `place`, `state`,
>   `user_id`) VALUES ('asd', 'gunung', 'asd', 'asd', NULL)
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/login-ci/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

**and this is my model**

```
public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->session->users['user_id'];
    }
```

**this is my controller**

```
public function addTrip(){
        $this->load->model('userModel');
        $user_id = $this->session->users['user_id'];

        $newTrip = ['name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                    'place' => $this->input->post('place'),
                    'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
                    'user_id' => $this->input->$user_id
                    ];


        $this->db->insert('adventure',$newTrip);
        // $this->db->insert('adventure',$data);

        redirect('userController/profile');
    }
```

please someone tell me if I miss something in my code, thanks alot

Comment: Have you tried: `'user_id' => getUserId()` instead?

Comment: duplicate of:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430501/codeigniter-how-to-insert-user-id-to-mysql-when-that-user-id-is-logged-in

Comment: I tried @JorgeCampos and still same the value was NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issue in creating array for insert. change your code as:

```
$user_id = $this->session->users['user_id'];
$newTrip = ['name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                    'category' => $this->input->post('category'),
                    'place' => $this->input->post('place'),
                    'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
                    'user_id' => $user_id // You already have $user_id from session
                    ];
```

Comment: Is your user_id stored in session?

Comment: yes it is, when I check on the view I can get the username session, but when I want get the user_id and insert to mySQL is always NULL

Comment: change `$this->session->users['user_id'];` to `$this->session->userdata('user_id);`

Comment: still error dude, I really confuse => Error Number: 1048

Column 'user_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `adventure` (`name`, `category`, `place`, `state`, `user_id`) VALUES ('asd', 'gunung', 'sad', 'sad', NULL)

Comment: Is your your session returning correct value? what is output of `$this->session->userdata('user_id);`?

Comment: when I return the page is blank and when I check in ctr+U the page is only show "1", and when I echo the page still white screen or blank, but when I tried change the user_id to username the username was show

Comment: so you don't have assign session value to `user_id`? At the time of assigning `username`, also assign `user_id` to session

Comment: please check my answer bellow where should I input user_id so that I can get the value.. thanks

Comment: After `$_SESSION['username'] = $username->username;` add `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $username->user_id;`

Answer (score 0):

If you stored user id in session then this are the possible 3 way to get your session value.

```
1) $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
2) $user = $this->session->user_id;
3) $user = $this->session->userdata('user_id);
```

For more details you can visits here:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: after I tried with that my user_id wasn't stored only username that was stored, so need find out how to stored my user_id now. thanks